# For statement missing letter in print

Tags: javascript

I need to print all the characters on the hacker1 const, separated by a space and in capitals but i'm only priting three letters. Got stuck in this? Can someone give me a hint?

```js
const hacker1 = "joe"
const hacker2 = "john"
let name = " ";
for (let i = 0; i < hacker1.length; i++) {
name += hacker2[i].toUpperCase() + ' '; 
}
console.log(name); // Result is JOH
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looping over `hacker1` but referring to `hacker2` inside the for loop.